How to build expression in ADF from json using parameterized variable?
I have one activity output like this
{
    "firstRow": {
        "mapping": "{\"CHRSCRT\":\"CHRT\",\"CST\":\"CUSTOM\"}"
    }
}

an second activity output like
{
    "name": "FF",
    "value": "CST"
}

Now i want to take only one value from mapping table using the second variable.
I tried
@{json(activity('1stActivity').output.firstRow.mapping)}.@{variables('secondActivity')}}

I want output like CUSTOM
But i am getting output {\"CHRSCRT\":\"CHRT\",\"CST\":\"CUSTOM\"}.CST
Please help in this expression builder in ADF.

are you getting any error?

@RakeshGovindula no I am not getting error but I need desired result, how can I get that?


I want output like CUSTOM

To achieve your requirement, you can modify your dynamic expression without string interpolation like below.
@json(activity('1stActivity').output.firstRow.mapping)[variables('secondActivity')]


Here, it uses [] notation instead of . to specify the key from the secondActivity output.
Result:

